# Is "privileged information" confidential?

Tags: discussion, votes, privileges

I'm asking specifically about $2$ privileges right now

- **750 rep** - View vote counts
- **5k rep** - View site analysis data

For the 5k privilege, it explicitly states that you are discouraged from sharing the raw data with others. **Is the same true for the vote counts?**

For example, if I let my friend know the number of up and down votes on his own Q, I don't see any harm in it. At the same time, it has been restricted to users $\geq 750$ rep, so there must be a reason for doing so (or so I assume).

Comment: Just tell your friend to [install this user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't make you sign an NDA when you hit those privilege levels. They are intended as privileges, not burdens. If you feel like sharing vote splits, you may. But if you don't want to, that's ok too. The primary reason vote splits are restricted is [performance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/1438).

I added the request to not share the analytics data because I think it preserves the value of the privilege. It's easy enough to copy the data to a GitHub repository or [something](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/what-are-the-current-traffic-and-usage-patterns-of-this-site) to make it available to anyone. But to some degree that devalues the benefit of the privilege for everyone else who has earned it.

Even so, secrecy is not the primary concern with limiting this information. Rather, we want you to use the information to help make the site better. If revealing some bit of data can improve the way your community functions (even indirectly), then please do so.